# Mysql-Java Batch insert handling out of memory error

Tags: java, mysql

I want to ask, is it normal to handle `OutOfMemoryError` while doing batch-inserts?

I am using following code to batch-insert in mysql:

```
try
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    con = Manager.getInstance().getConnection();
    ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO" + 
    " movie_release_date_pushed_to_subscriber"
    + "(movie_id,cinema_id,msisdn,sent_timestamp)VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

    for (String msisdn : subscriberBatch)
    {
        try
        {
            ps.setInt(1, movieToBeReleased.getMovieId());
            ps.setInt(2, movieToBeReleased.getCinemaId());
            ps.setString(3, msisdn);
            ps.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            ps.addBatch();
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError oome)
        {
            ....
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    }

    ps.executeBatch();
}
catch (Throwable e)
{
    ....
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        Manager.getInstance().close(ps);
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Any kind of advice/recommendation is most welcome,

Comment: Do you get a lot of `OutOfMemoryErrors` based on the size of the batch?

Comment: Not a lot, but I want to place the check just to be safe.(And I can't guess the appropriate batch-size, as I don't know on which machine will this app run)

Comment: I am afraid if there is no space in JVM then how can you do addition execute in same JVM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No its *not* normal. And your catch handler is totally ineffective. Catching an OOME does not miraculously solve its root cause - exhaustion of program memory. You get that error *after* the runtime has made a best effort at reclaiming memory, and failed. You should not be trying to execute code at that point, you may not even be able to log messages!

If you feel for whatever reason that your batch statement may cause an OOME, then you should either:

- Break up the batch cycle into smaller 'buckets'
- Make more memory available to the program

Comment: Is there any way to know if JVM is near `OOME`, before it actually occurs?

Comment: @djaqeel - Sure. You can use a [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) to receive notifications on your heap usage. Thats from within your program. You can also monitor the application externally, using a tool like JVisualVM (thats more for debugging than anything else).

Comment: If you could include `MemoryMXBean` into your answer, than it would be a ***more complete*** answer.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to try to execute the batch if you get an `OutOfMemoryError`. However, you can replace your `INSERT` query with an `INSERT IGNORE INTO` and in case of an OOME, ask the user to run the batch again after restarting JVM.

What `INSERT IGNORE INTO` will do is not run the insert if the primary key already exists in the table, so your batch will resume from where it crashed the app.

However, I will have to warn you that this is probably a very dirty way to circumvent this situation.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's a workaround. If you keep getting the OOME, then you might want to look into better memory management.